# OpenID Security - Bogus OpenID Redirect

Tags: security, openid

I'm trying to figure out how a site that accepts OpenID logins couldn't be hacked by a simple hosts file update to point to a bogus OpenID provider.

Lets say for instance I want to hack into Joe Smith's account and for this example, lets pretend his OpenID provider is http://jsmith.myopenid.com. What would prevent me from creating an entry in my hosts file, pointing jsmith.myopenid.com to an IP that I control. I would then fake the authentication and return a response saying that the user successfully logged in.

I know there would be an SSL mismatch warning in the browser, but since it's my browser I could easily ignore it. How does the requesting website know that the response it receives is actually from the site that was requested?

This seems like a basic attack, and I'm sure the people behind have included a solution for this, I just must not be searching on the correct terms to find the answer.

Comment: It seems the site you're accessing also contacts the OpenID provider directly to verify that. From wikipedia: "...then the user-agent is redirected back to the relying party along with the end-user's credentials. That relying party must then confirm that the credentials really came from the OpenID provider. If the relying party and OpenID provider had previously established a shared secret, then the relying party can validate the identity of the OpenID provider by comparing its copy of the shared secret against the one received along with the end-user's credentials..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relying party contacts the OpenID provider directly, either before authentication (to establish a shared secret key used to put an HMAC on the OpenID provider's response) or after authentication (to ask it to confirm the response actually came from the OpenID provider).

For your attack to work, you would also need to be able to control DNS lookups of the relying party, not just your own.